# How do display a list of packages a certain package provides for?

Tags: fedora, package-management, repository, dnf

On Fedora, I can get a list of packages another package depends on, with the following command:

```
dnf repoquery --requires --resolve <package>
```

But I'd like to have the *opposite* of that.

I.e. listing all packages, the package that I'm querying for depend on.

If possible, either for only installed packages, and perhaps for all packages in my repos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

could be `dnf repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires` to get the reverse dependencies

Comment: that and `--installed` instead of `--alldeps`, thanks!